# iptable matching rule for STUN/TURN traffic

Tags: iptables, nat

I am looking for finding TURN/STUN packets coming on a 443 port.
According to the TURN RFC, Bytes 46 to 49 are TURN packet magic cookie '2112a442'. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euliT.jpg) is the screenshot from wireshark where I found the STUN cookie to be from 46 to 49

I am using `-m u32 --u32 "46=0x2112A442"`  but am not able to filter them.

Here is my complete iptable rule

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m u32 --u32 "46=0x2112A442" -j REDIRECT --to-port 3478
```

Any Idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the entire iptables command line, and perhaps some overall context (i.e. you entire iptables rule set).

Comment: How did you get the offset of 46? I calculate 24, but am finding it hard to figure out for certain.

Comment: I got it from wireshark. I captured some wireshark STUN packets and all of them have the magic cookie at this location 46. Please find the screenshot attached from wireshark

Comment: Yes, but I do not think that the u32 module includes the ethernet wrapper bytes, so its offset needs to be different (try 32). It is late in my time zone, I'll work on this tomorrow. Thanks for the wireshark screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iptables u32 module offsets are referenced to the packet minus the ethernet wrapper (minus the source and destination MAC, 6 bytes each, and the ether type, 2 bytes. Therefore your wireshark offset of 46 needs to adjusted by 14, and should be 32.

Now, for a sanity check, find the type of service byte, which we know from the u32 area of [the man pages for iptables-extensions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/iptables-extensions.8.htm) is at offset 9 and we also know is 0x11 (17) for UDP. It is at byte 0x17 (23) of your wireshark screenshot. Counting from there, we also get 32 as the offset you should be using.

EDIT 1: Since the protocol is UDP, you also need to adjust that part of your iptables command. So:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 443 -m u32 --u32 "32=0x2112A442" -j REDIRECT --to-port 3478
```

EDIT 2: In your example wireshark screen shot, the destination port is 5004, not 443. So the iptables command still will not work for your particular packet example. Maybe this:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 5004 -m u32 --u32 "32=0x2112A442" -j REDIRECT --to-port 3478
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Doug! That did helped me. It worked for udp!
However, TCP packets still I am unable to match. I used  44 (+12 for TCP ) Am I missing something here?

Comment: I only learned about this stuff yesterday, but thought that STUN was only on UDP. I do not know about STUN on TCP. Maybe start a new question for TCP, and include a wireshark screenshot again, and include a reference to this question.

Comment: Thats awesome. STUN can used on both tcp and udp. I need to collect wirehark logs. I will start a new question with wireshark log tomorrow.